# Cannot install XNA 4 redist on WIndows 7 64bit....Any ideas?

Tags: .net, frameworks, xna

Specs: I7-920, Asus P6T, 6GB DDR3, GTX660, SSD+5HDD, Windows 7 64bit

I recently bought couple of games and i seem to have the same problem again and again. They both require XNA 4 and it is included in the game files. When i try to install, though, during installation a error pops out saying that xnavisualizer.dll cannot be registered or something. I don't know why this is happening and i have tried, literally, every solution out there. From re-installing all .NET framework or Visual C++ programs to anything you can imagine. Can someone please explain why NOTHING works and how i can fix it? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Perhaps a reinstall of [DirectX](http://www.microsoft.com/en-AU/download/details.aspx?id=35) since XNA depends on it

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the redistribute online: [Click here to go to the Download Page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=20914).

[image: Here is the Related Information]

Answer (score -1):

Yea unfortunately nothing works and that's not an advice when i already said that installing DINDT WORK. Anyways i re-installed Windows 7 and now it works. I am guessing it was some sort of hang-up between so many .NET C++ etc etc redist's that stuff got mixed up.